# Deploying C# Projects from Visual Studio 2017 for MacOS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment, publish, macos-high-sierra

I've been working with Visual Studio 2017 for Mac for a while now and I'm not having any luck actually finding a way to deploy, package, or compile my project into a release executable. I only have my development files and folders. This is a C# console application.

There don't seem to be any versions of VS2017 for MacOS other than the community version. I can see the dropdown on their website for professional/enterprise, but the download is for the same nondescript visual studio with no options to change version or initiate a trial.

This seems either like I am missing something big or a very silly thing to omit.

Xamarin Studio now diverts users to Visual Studio.

Can I get some help?

Comment: What kind of "deployment" do you want for console applications? macOS does not support MSI installers, and you might deploy via other methods, such as Homebrew.

Comment: @LexLi I suppose I'm hoping to end up with the output of an MSI... any idea where to find info on how I could package that up and deploy through something like that?